# Check the value of all rows in a column to see if it is in a list, return bool value, without for loop

Tags: r, list, dataframe, recode

I have a data frame column named as "occupation" with values 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. I need to construct a new data frame column, say occupation2. Rows in the new column will take value 1 if the value in the old column belongs to one of the elements: 2,3,6,7. Otherwise, rows will take 0. In my real data, there are about 90 different values can be taken by the "occupation" column. Also, there are about 10 different values I need to use to assign 1 to the new column. So I don't want to create about 10 different conditions to assign the new value.

What I did is creating a list containing the value based on which I can dichotomize the new column, say value_list = c(2, 3, 6, 7). I also try to avoid using for loop to complete the task. A pseudo code would look like the following:

```
df$occupation2 <- 0 
value_list = c(2, 3, 6, 7)
df['occupation2'] <- 1 where occupation2's value isin value_list.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df[['occupation2']] <- as.integer(df[['occupation']] %in% value_list)` should work. `%in%` is the perfect operator for this job. It returns a `logical` (TRUE/FALSE) vector, which will be converted to 1/0 by `as.integer()`.

(Also, when extracting a single column from a data frame, either use `data[, column]` or `data[[column]]` to access the column directly - `data[column]` will give a 1-column data frame, rather than just the column)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have a follow up question. I know if python pandas data frame. using df['col'] returns you an array, while using df[['col']] will return you a single column pd data frame. If you need to extra a "sub data frame" with multiple columns, you use df[['col1','col2']].

Comment: My understanding is that you are passing a list containing names of columns you are interested in to the subsetting brackets. However, I have a hard time to understand the logic here in R. Also, it seems to me that whenever I need to get a boolean vector, both [] and [[]] works. Could you tell me about this, or point me to a place where I can understand it fully?

Comment: R doesn't use `['a', 'b']` as vector/array syntax, it uses `c('a', 'b')`. If you make that translation, then your examples from python are almost exactly equivalent in R. `df['col']` is a 1-column data frame, `df[['col']]` is a vector. `df[c('col1', 'col2')]` is a 2 column data frame, and is equivalent to `df[, c('col1, 'col2'])`.

Comment: Thx : ) It clarifies a lot of confusion.